# CircularReferenceException when letting subprojects depend on other subprojects

Tags: gradle, build, build.gradle

In my project I have 6 sub projects, all of which depend on each other.

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":common")
        compile project(":def")
        compile project(":fs")
        compile project(":game")
        compile project(":network")
        compile project(":parser")

        ... remainder omitted
    }

}
```

When declaring the dependencies like this in my main projects build.gradle file I get a circular dependency error.

I have also tried declaring the dependencies each sub project depends on in their own build.gradle only to receive the same error.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: If A depends on B, B can't depends on A. Then what you are doing is wrong,

Comment: Can't that work vice versa like I would be able to do in a Maven module? @GabrieleMariotti

Comment: It is not a gradle problem. You can't realize a similar dependency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to realize somenthing like this:

**Proj A:**

```
dependencies {
        compile project(":B)
        compile project(":C")
}
```

**Proj B:**

```
dependencies {
        compile project(":A)
        compile project(":C")
}
```

**Proj C:**

```
dependencies {
        compile project(":B)
        compile project(":A")
}
```

It is a **CircularReference**.
**If A depends on B, B can't depends on A.**

You can't do it.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Is there a way to allow sub projects to depend on one another like I would be able to do in a Maven module?

Comment: Of course a subproject can have a dependency with another project. Also you can define a common dependency. That a look here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html